# 4th order Runge-Kutta function with controller in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, controller, runge-kutta

I'm trying to solve a system of equations defined in a function ('f') using a 4th order Runge-Kutta method, taking into account a PD controller on a variable ('c').

Here is how my code looks like so far:

```
 t_f = 100; % simulation end time
 h = 0.1;   % sample time
 K = 1;     % controller gain
 Td = 10;   % controller derivative time
 x = [...]; % initial conditions
 N = round(t_f/h); % number of samples
 xout = zeros(N+1,length(x)+2); % memory allocation

 for i=1:N+1
     time = (i-1)*h; % simulation time
     a = x(1);
     if (a<10)
        a_ref = 1; % desired 'a' value
        c = K*((a-a_ref)+Td); % controller

 [x v] = RK4('f',x,[c 0],h,i);
 xout(i,:) = [time,x',v]
```

I'm struggling to write the RK4 function to solve the equations from 'f', also making sure the controller is used.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

EDIT:

Following this [link](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math579w10/matlab/rk4.m), I've now written a separate function that looks like this:

```
function [x v] = RK4(f,a,t_f,x,N)
a = 0;
t_f = 100;
h = 0.1;
N = round(t_f/h);
% h = (t_f - a) / N;
halfh = h / 2;
x(1,:) = x;
v(1) = a;
h6 = h/6;

for i = 1 : N
    v(i+1) = v(i) + h;
    vh2 = v(i) + halfh;
    s1 = f(v(i), x(i,:));
    s2 = f(vh2, x(i,:) + halfh * s1);
    s3 = f(vh2, x(i,:) + halfh * s2);
    s4 = f(v(i+1), x(i,:) + h * s3);
    x(i+1,:) = x(i,:) + (s1 + s2+s2 + s3+s3 + s4) * h6;
end;
```

When running the main script this returns the error at line starting with "s1 = ..." in the for loop:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Plus, I'm not sure if the controller input needs to be incorporated in this function.

Sorry if this is straightforward, but I'm struggling to get my head around it.

Thanks.

EDIT 2:

The latest version of the code can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlE-fessx_K3gwBIszRrbj81EgNn).
The main loop is in *Tacking.m* (calling other functions) and the Runge-Kutta integration is in *RK4.m*.

I've tried several formulations but, as you can see, I'm not sure how to write it properly in this case.

Note: all the other functions were previously used, it's the "solver" that I need to get sorted.

Any help would be welcomed. Thanks !

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math579w10/matlab/rk4.m).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I've edited my post taking into consideration your link. As you can see I'm struggling to write the function properly. Cheers.

Comment: Did you test your integration routine with a simple test example like f(x,y)=x, f(x,y)=y or similar? Show your function f as that is probably where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL. The code is [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlE-fessx_K3gwBIszRrbj81EgNn). The main loop is in _Tacking.m_ and the Runge-Kutta function in _RK4.m_. I know the code has been used in the past, but it's the RK4 function that I'm struggling to write properly. Thanks !